# What is causing my vehicle to make slight slips and harsh noise in Wet condition uphill starts?

Tags: toyota, camry

I have a Toyota Camry 2002. The vehicle runs normally. But for the last few months, I am noticing my vehicle slips slightly and the tires make harsh sound with the road when I try to start from a uphill stop sign in WET conditions. The problem does not happen in dry weathers. I have installed all season tires last year and never had this problem before.

One day I had the same problem in the freeway while I was driving downhill. The tire made harsh sound the car appeared to slip away. I had hard time to brake.

Comment: How old are the tires?

Comment: Front pairs are two years and rear pairs are one year. Although they have 70000 miles lifetime. I did not drive them more than 15000 miles.

Comment: Manual or automatic transmission?

Comment: 15k miles is not to be sniffed at, the fact that it only seems to be happening in the wet makes me think the tires are getting too worn to clear the water properly, although the behaviour sounds extreme for that. Possibly some kind of wheel speed sensor issue in play?

Comment: Wheel spin doesn't sound like it does in the movies.  What you're describing really does sound like the tires slipping on wet roads.

Comment: If the car is equipped with traction control, it may be the actuation of that system as the tires start to slip on the wet pavement.

Comment: How deep is the tread on the tires? Any uneven wear? What's the manufacture date on the tires, maybe they were already a few years old when you bought them. Have you driven that car with all season tires before? Possibly it's just a tire brand with harder rubber & easier to slip than you're used to, hitting the gas hard from an uphill stop in the rain in a FWD car is much more likely to spin a tire